# Problem returning tokenURI(string) from contract

Tags: contract-invocation, nft, nethereum, c#

I'm trying to return information from a contract, most specifically the tokenURI. My problem is that I cannot visualize the result... it seems to be empty when it was supposed to be a string. I must be doing something dumb that I cannot find. Here's my code:

```
var contractAddress = "0x96e7F29eD63dcB293292F0036c8e15B49a198902";
var abi =
            @"[{""inputs"":[],""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""constructor""},{""anonymous"":false,""inputs"":[{""indexed"":true,""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""owner"",""type"":""address""},{""indexed"":true,""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""approved"",""type"":""address""},{""indexed"":true,""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""tokenId"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""Approval"",""type"":""event""},{""anonymous"":false,""inputs"":[{""indexed"":true,""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""owner"",""type"":""address""},{""indexed"":true,""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""operator"",""type"":""address""},{""indexed"":false,""internalType"":""bool"",""name"":""approved"",""type"":""bool""}],""name"":""ApprovalForAll"",""type"":""event""},{""anonymous"":false,""inputs"":[{""indexed"":true,""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""from"",""type"":""address""},{""indexed"":true,""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""to"",""type"":""address""},{""indexed"":true,""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""tokenId"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""Transfer"",""type"":""event""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""to"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""tokenId"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""approve"",""outputs"":[],""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""owner"",""type"":""address""}],""name"":""balanceOf"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":"""",""type"":""uint256""}],""stateMutability"":""view"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""_newOwner"",""type"":""address""}],""name"":""changeOwner"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""bool"",""name"":"""",""type"":""bool""}],""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""_itemOwner"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""_id"",""type"":""uint256""},{""internalType"":""string"",""name"":""_tokenURI"",""type"":""string""}],""name"":""forgeNewNFT"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""bool"",""name"":"""",""type"":""bool""}],""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""tokenId"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""getApproved"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":"""",""type"":""address""}],""stateMutability"":""view"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""owner"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""operator"",""type"":""address""}],""name"":""isApprovedForAll"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""bool"",""name"":"""",""type"":""bool""}],""stateMutability"":""view"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[],""name"":""name"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""string"",""name"":"""",""type"":""string""}],""stateMutability"":""view"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""tokenId"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""ownerOf"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":"""",""type"":""address""}],""stateMutability"":""view"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""from"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""to"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""tokenId"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""safeTransferFrom"",""outputs"":[],""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""from"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""to"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""tokenId"",""type"":""uint256""},{""internalType"":""bytes"",""name"":""_data"",""type"":""bytes""}],""name"":""safeTransferFrom"",""outputs"":[],""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""operator"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""bool"",""name"":""approved"",""type"":""bool""}],""name"":""setApprovalForAll"",""outputs"":[],""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""bytes4"",""name"":""interfaceId"",""type"":""bytes4""}],""name"":""supportsInterface"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""bool"",""name"":"""",""type"":""bool""}],""stateMutability"":""view"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[],""name"":""symbol"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""string"",""name"":"""",""type"":""string""}],""stateMutability"":""view"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""tokenId"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""tokenURI"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""string"",""name"":"""",""type"":""string""}],""stateMutability"":""view"",""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""from"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""address"",""name"":""to"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""tokenId"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""transferFrom"",""outputs"":[],""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""function""}]";

var web3 = new Web3(infuraURL);
var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(abi, contractAddress);
var tokenFunction = contract.GetFunction("tokenURI");
BigInteger myToken = 1;
var myResult = await tokenFunction.CallAsync<string>(myToken);
```

I was then trying to use

```
Debug.Log("result = " + myResult);
```

to check the string acquired but I get this printed in my console:

```
result =
```

when it was supposed to be this:

```
result = https://nifiti.io/nft/1.json
```

where the URL is the result I get when I manually use the query field of the contract inputting the value 1.
What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I am assuming the `tokenFunction` to `tokenURIFunction` difference is a typo that is only on stack exchange?

Comment: @Richard Yeap. Sorry. It was only a typo here, the original code is correct. I just fixed it to avoid confusion.